# QMdiArea SetActiveSubWindow changing

Tags: qt, overriding, qmdiarea

I have some application and need someone who advices me what to do. I need to use `setActiveSubWindow(QmdiSubWindow *window)` method, but it takes as a parameter an instance of `QMdiSubWindow` class, but my windows is not an instance of this class. So what should i do? Is there some way to convert my windows or to override this method?

Comment: [`QMdiArea::addSubWindow(QWidget * widget, Qt::WindowFlags windowFlags = 0)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmdiarea.html#addSubWindow) returns a `QMdiSubWindow` pointer. Can't you just use that?

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. In my application I have a List<MyWindow*> list - it is a list which contains my windows, and i can work only with this list.

Comment: @zuzman322, and what is `MyWindow`?

Comment: it's a class inherited from QMainWindow class.

Comment: @zuzman322, so you have a `QMainWindow` that has sub windows each of them containing another `QMainWindow`?

Comment: no, i have a list which contains "MyWindow"s and i need to switch between them by clicking different buttons. Something like that)